# Parse elements into vector using boost::spirit, using semicolon or newlines as separators

Tags: c++, parsing, boost, boost-spirit

I'd like to parse a sequence of integers into an `std::vector<int>`, using `boost::spirit`. The integers may be separated by a semicolon or a newline.

But this grammar doesn't compile:

```
typedef std::vector<int> IntVec;
template <typename Iterator, typename Skipper>
struct MyGrammar : qi::grammar<Iterator, IntVec(), Skipper> {
  MyGrammar() : MyGrammar::base_type(start) {
    start = +(qi::int_
              >> (";" | qi::no_skip(qi::eol)));
  }
  qi::rule<Iterator, IntVec(), Skipper> start;
};
```

To be clear, I want to parse the following input, for example,

```
1; 2; 3
4 ; 5
```

into one vector `(1,2,3,4,5)`. How can I do that and why does my version not compile?

Can I somehow write the separator ("semicolon or newline") as its own rule? What would its return type be? Some kind of `null` value?

Comment: Your reputation and badges are so.... special :) I'll print-screen them!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the skipper is being applied when checking the semicolon, and so the skip characters (including newline) have already been consumed once `qi::no_skip[qi::eol]` is reached. The following is working for me, with the `no_skip` token first:

```
    start = qi::int_ % (qi::no_skip[qi::eol] | ';');
```

I'm using `%` so that the final integer does not need to be followed by a semicolon or end-of-line.